# Errata for the Treatise of Analysis of Dieudonné

Tags: measure-theory

I was looking again at the beautiful and quite complete work of Dieudonné, his Treatise of Analysis, to refresh my memory about some aspects of classical analysis. I especially love this Treatise for the quality of its exercises. Unfortunately, some of them are marred with plain mistakes or wrong hints, and make me waste a lot of time detecting all of them. Does anybody know a reliable errata for the volume 2 of this treatise ?

Here below is one instance of a plain wrong hint in an exercise, and a sketch of a solution I found.

I would very much appreciate if somebody could give some kind of reassurance that I am on the right track here and that my solutions are correct.

Here is the text of the exercise:
[image]

The hint is obviously wrong because it is not possible to have the inequality $b\mu(A\cap F_q)\leq a\mu(A)$ for $q=n$ for instance.

Below is a solution I found for comments

Notation for $p\geq n\geq 0$ :

$$\begin{align*}
A_{n}^p &=\left\{x\in X\ ;\ \sup_{p\geq r\geq n}f_{r}(x)\geq b\right\} \\
B_{n}^p &=\left\{x\in X\ ;\ \inf_{p\geq r\geq n}f_{r}(x)\leq a\right\} \\
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{alignat*}{2}
A_{n} &=\bigcup_{p\geq n} A_{n}^p &\quad B_{n} &=\bigcup_{p\geq n} B_{n}^p \\
A &=\bigcap_{n\geq 0}A_{n} &\quad B &=\bigcap_{n\geq 0}B_{n}
\end{alignat*}$$

Then we have $E_{ab}=A\cap B$. We also note that the unions and intersections in the previous definitions are respectively increasing and decreasing sequences.

Choose $r\geq s\geq p\geq q\geq m\geq n$.
First we notice that $$A_{n}^m = \bigcup_{m\geq i\geq n} \left\{x\in X\ ;\ f_{n}(x)<b, \cdots, f_{i-1}(x)<b,\ f_{i}(x)\geq b\right\}$$ the union being of disjoints sets.
By definition of a martingale, for $i\leq m$, we have $$\int_{x\in X\ ;\ f_n(x)<\cdots,f_{i−1}(x)<b,\ f_i(x\geq b} f_i\ d\mu=\int_{x\in X\ ;\ f_n(x)<\cdots,f_{i−1}(x)<b,\ f_i(x\geq b}f_m\ d\mu$$
Then, we get $$\int_{A_n^m}f_{m}d\mu \geq b\mu(A_{n}^m)$$
For the same reasons, we also get $$\int_{B_{n}^m}f_{m}d\mu \leq a\mu(B_{n}^m)$$

Therefore, we deduce that $$\int_{A_{n}^m\cap B_{q}^p \cap A_{s}^r}f_{r} d\mu \geq b\mu(A_{n}^m\cap B_{q}^p \cap A_{s}^r)$$
and $$\int_{A_{n}^m\cap B_{q}^p \cap A_{s}^r}f_{r}d\mu \leq \int_{A_{n}^m\cap B_{q}^p}f_{r}d\mu =\int_{A_{n}^m\cap B_{q}^p}f_{p}d\mu \leq a\mu(A_{n}^m\cap B_{q}^p) \leq a\mu(A_{n}^m\cap B_{q})$$

Let $$b\mu(A_{n}^m\cap B_{q}^p \cap A_{s}^r) \leq a\mu(A_{n}^m\cap B_{q})$$

By successively having $r$ then $s$ then $p$ then $q$ goes towards infinity we get $$b\mu(A_{n}^m\cap B \cap A)\leq a\mu(A_{n}^m\cap B)$$
If $m$ then $n$ goes towards infinity we get $$b\mu(E_{ab})\leq a\mu(E_{ab})$$ QEA.

Comment: This question ask two not really that related questions in one. This is undesirable.